# Holt-winter model fit values

Tags: forecast, model-fitting, holtwinters

Hw to get model fit model for training period in holt winter method for Univariate time series. For future forecast I can use the following syntax but not sure what is syntax for training period.

````
                result = model.fit()
                start = len(df)
                end = len(df) + 6
                # Predictions for one-year against the test set
                
                fcast = result.forecast(start ,end)```
````

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer it is
`result.fittedvalues`